# jQuery css() not working with visibility

Tags: jquery, css

In the code below I have changed `show()` to `css()` and modified the visibility. For some reason it doesn't show up onclick.

Here is the HTML:

```
<td class="area">
    <img src="/def.jpg" />
</td>

<tr id="target" style="visibility:hidden">
    <td>This was hidden</td>
</tr>
```

and then the jQuery:

```
$("td.area").on("click", "img", function(){
    $("tr:hidden#target").css("visibility","visible");
});
```

Comment: I got your jquery scroller solution for you buddy, but you deleted the question before I could post an answer. Not sure what happened there. Let me know if you still need it. I can post it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use `$('tr#target')`. See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/Tk2H6/) here.

Answer (score 10):

The selector **:hidden** does not work with **visibility** just with **display**. Here is the jQuery documentation http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

You have to try something different:

```
var t = $("#target");
if(t.css("visibility") == "hidden"){
    t.css("visibility", "visible"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would personally write it like this.

NOTE: I did not test this.

```
<style>
  #target {visibility: hidden}
</style>

<script>
   $('td.area').live('click', function(){
       if ($('#target').is(":visible")) {
         // Do something?
       } 
       else {
         // Make visible
         $('#target').css('visibility', 'visible') 
       }
   });
</script>

<td class="area"><img src="/def.jpg" /></td>
<tr id="target">
   <td>This was hidden </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) for `:hidden`. Elements with `visibility:hidden` cannot be considered `:hidden`.

The solution would be to just target the `tr` without the `:hidden` selector, like so:

```
$("tr#target").css("visibility","visible");
```

Comment: No, didn't work. If I change it to display:none and show() it works fine though :o/

Comment: Well obviously. `visibility:hidden` won't count as `:hidden`. See my edit.